# Apex REST web service with Enhanced Domains over HTTP/2

Tags: apex, webservices, enhanced-domains

I have created a public rest web service.
It's HTTP POST and while calling that from Postman, I'm getting the below error:

```
{
        "errorCode": "METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED",
        "message": "HTTP Method 'GET' not allowed. Allowed are POST"
    }
```

I created a get method and it seems to be working fine.

Web Service Class:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Disposition')
global class CallDisposition {

    @HttpGet
    global static String doGet() {
        String name = RestContext.request.params.get('data');
        return 'Hello '+name;
    }
    
    @HttpPost
    global static void CreateActivity() {
        String data = '';
       
      
       data = RestContext.request.params.get('data');
       
       system.debug('>>> data... '+data);
}
}
```

My URL for both the call is
**`ptcgroup--cti.sandbox.my.salesforce-sites.com/services/apexrest/Disposition?data=Pat`**

with GET and POST method.

Comment: `https://ptcgroup--cti.sandbox.my.salesforce-sites.com/services/apexrest/Disposition?data=Pat` doesn't resolve when punched into a browser

Comment: original URL is dtcgroup--cti.sandbox.my.salesforce-sites.com/services/apexrest/CallDisposition?data=Pat

Comment: Sending a GET by entering the URL into the browser works for us - we see `<response>Hello Pat</response>` as the output

Comment: ....but doing this with `curl` leads to a 500. Looking at dev tools in Chrome where it works, the request/response and a follow-up request are HTTP/2. This is due to [Enhanced Domains](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.domain_name_enhanced.htm&language=en_US&type=5) enabled in your org - disable it and try again.

Comment: I have one existing public API, which seems to be working fine, not sure how it's getting called

Comment: Please edit your question and include the working test case